# I keep getting the error cannot call recv() while another coroutine is already waiting for the next message

Tags: javascript, python, websocket

When I run my paddleLogic function twice I get the error "cannot call recv() while another coroutine is already waiting for the next message" Even though I am using await to ensure that they are not trying to receive at the same time.

I have run the code without calling the paddleLogic function the second time, and everything works as expected

```python
    leftPaddlePos = await paddleLogic(websocket,leftPaddlePos)
    rightPaddlePos = await paddleLogic(opponent[websocket],rightPaddlePos)

async def paddleLogic(socket,pos):
        try:
            key = await asyncio.wait_for(socket.recv(),timeout=0.01)
            if key == "1" and pos > 0:
                pos = pos - 1
            elif key == "2" and pos < 60:
                pos = pos + 1
            time.sleep(0.003)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            pos = pos
        return pos
```

Sorry if this post is kind of a mess, this is my first time asking a question on stackoverflow. If you want more information/code I'm happy to provide it.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get your sockets?

What we have is coroutines. They are scheduled by them yielding control to one another. They yield control when they call `await`. It appears that your `socket.recv`
 also does some waiting behind the scenes by yielding control, so `recv` is entered twice if data from network are not immediately available.

I suppose that you'd be better off [accessing asyncio event loop socket support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#working-with-socket-objects-directly). Otherwise, I'd use `select()` to look at *both* sockets in parallel,  returned events like `('left paddle', -1)` from my async generator, and updated the game world accordingly.

(I can even suppose that a real-time game like pong would be easier to implement in a completely synchronous way, paced by frame rate.)

Comment: using socket.receive() would I need to know the number of bytes of the received message before it is received?